PrimeVue FileUpload - Handle server upload error
When uploading files, server might return an error.
I can access the error through the event error:
@error="onUploadError"

However, I do not manage to manipulate the file list in order to remove them from preview.
Is it a way to access the uploader-state?

You cannot directly modify the FileUpload component, but by defining it as a ref, you can clear it by calling an internal API function: clear().


const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    const fileUploader = ref(null);
    
    const onUploadError = (event) => {
      console.error("Upload Error");

      // Access the FileUpload component via ref and clear the file list
      if (fileUploader.value) {
        fileUploader.value.clear();
      }
    }

    return {
      fileUploader,
      onUploadError,
    };
  },
});

app.use(PrimeVue.Config, {
  theme: {
    preset: PrimeVue.Themes.Aura,
  },
});

app.component('p-fileupload', PrimeVue.FileUpload);

app.mount('#app');
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue/umd/primevue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@primevue/themes/umd/aura.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p-fileupload
    ref="fileUploader"
    url="/nonexistent-url-error-simulation"
    @error="onUploadError"
    :auto="true"
  />
</div>




Remove all files with clear API function - PrimeVue Docs
Remove a file with remove API function - PrimeVue Docs

